# Can High Wind Speed break Laminated Glass and bend Steel Pipes?

Tags: steel, glass, wind

Planning on using Steel Pipes as frames for holding laminated glass in a high wind area. Four sides will be covered by glass and the roofing will be also be covered with glass. Planning on using a frame to hold the vertical glass and for roofing support for the glass as well. The dimensions of the area is approximately 9ft in width,16ft in length and 8ft in height.Can high wind(around 150 miles per hour) bend the steel pipes and break the laminated glass? Are there any other materials I need to consider in such a high wind speed region?

Comment: one would also need to know the properties of the steel and cross sectional dimensions.  Based on our modeling theories, every thing bends no matter what amount load is applied to it.  The real question is what are your allowable limits for the bending.  This is where your regional building code will come into effect and you will need either an engineer or an architect to crunch some numbers and stand by the results.

Comment: Steel and glass would do find, if designed and constructed correctly.  This is not an overly big structure if you decide to go that route, you can be "self-insured" and do your own design and take your lumps should things go wrong.  I designed my front porch, working out the loading using what I learned in school (I took the PE class but not the exam) and then sat down with my friend, also an engineer who studied my design, asked about 1000 questions and said I was good to go.

Answer (score 2):

steel pipes and sheet glass are routinely destroyed in wind storms. For this reason, structures built of steel and covered with glass must be built in accordance with the *building code* for your region, which specifies how strong the steel and glass must be. If *not* constructed "to code", your insurance agent will refuse to cover the structure for damages incurred in a storm.

Comment: and if you don't have building codes for your area, look up the building codes for an area with similar climate, wind, etc.